# ¿Como editar el valor de una variable en powershell?

Tags: windows, script, powershell, windows-server, directorioactivo

Ante todo perdón por si hay errores de comprensión porque no soy de hacer muchas preguntas.

Estoy creando un script en un active directory, que entre otras cosas valide si un campo recibido (un grupo) está creado o no y si no lo está, que lo cree. Yo soy de la rama de Unix por lo que intento hacerlo parecido y hasta ahora tengo:

```
$creado = Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like $grupo} | select name 



if ($creado -eq $grupo){

  Write-Host "el grupo $grupo ya estaba creado. No se creará"


}else{

Write-Host "El grupo no existía. Se crea" 

}
```

La idea que tenía era obtener el nombre del grupo en la variable $creado y validarla para que creara el grupo, el problema es que haciéndolo por fuera, en poweshell ise la variable $creado tiene lo siguiente:

```
name                                                                                                                                             
----                                                                                                                                             
ASIR
```

Entonces lo que me hace es decirme siempre que el grupo no existía, cuando ese grupo sí que existe, supongo porque compara name con ASIR en el IF.

Se me ocurre poder quitarle las dos primeras líneas para quedarme solo con el nombre, pero desconozco muchísimo de estos cmdlets. Y con select-String tampoco funciona.

Ya estoy desesperado...

¿Podéis ayudarme por favor?

Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Entiendo que la finalidad del script es conocer si el grupo existe no?  o crear directamente uno? podrías usar algo como `$GroupExists = Get-ADGroup -Identity $GroupName` y despues `if ($GroupExists -eq $true){ #grupo existe }`

Comment: Correcto! es eso lo que quería. Al final lo conseguí despues de googlear a tope de otra forma ```dsquery  group $grupo -o rdn```. Muchas gracias por el aporte